# What is the procedure to reopen a question that was closed years ago?

Tags: support, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24590962/javascriptserializer-de-serializes-a-property-with-default-value-or-null) 2 years ago and it was voted to close

Today I have modified it and clicked on the `reopen` option. Now it says,

> You voted to reopen. 4 votes from other users are needed to reopen
>   this question

It's been two years, so my question is,

1. Will a moderator receive notification about my reopen request and cast his vote to open or close?
2. Should I contact other Stack Overflow members to cast a vote for reopening? At present, I don't know any other users in this site.
3. Should I ask a question in Meta and paste the link here so people will vote to reopen it? This approach should be avoided because it will result in asking countless number of questions related to reopening a question.
4. Should I paste my question link in a Stack Overflow chat group and ask the members to vote for reopen?
5. Does a question has compelling need? I believe every question in SO is meant to point in right direction if not possible to provide a direct solution
6. If there is no compelling need, should I leave it closed? Till now, I believed a question is closed because the quality of the question is poor in many aspects. If the user makes it a valid question through editing, they can give a re-open request.

Though, I am a member for more than 2 years, I am not aware of the process involved in reopening a question.

**Reason for re-opening the question:**

**Questions are closed because they are not deemed valid. Once it is valid, then what's wrong with re-opening them?**

Comment: All: this isn't a request for action or a rant. This is a valid support question from a user who is not familiar with the review, reopen, etc. Please hoid your downvotes.

Comment: Yes, I don't get the downvotes here too.

Comment: Your question entered the re-open queue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/12924464). Do note that on the previous occasions it didn't make it: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24590962/timeline

Comment: @rene, Thanks, I don't know SO has features to actually view the reopen queue including the people reviewed it

Comment: 10-kers have that option  @Anand and when the review is completed you can see it in the timeline on your post

Comment: All: My question is reopened, I really appreciate your help. I will try my best to post good questions which are clear and useful to everyone.

Comment: Glad it's all sorted out, and this question here got a positive score.

Answer (score 9):

> 1) Will a moderator receive notification about my reopen request and cast his vote to open or close ?

No, a moderator will not.  It will show up in the reopen queue for users with the reopen privilege, but they aren't going to be moderators.

> 2) Should I contact other stackoverflow members to cast a vote for reopening? At present, I don't know any other users in this site.

No.

> 3) Should I ask a question in meta and paste the link here so people will vote to reopen it? This approach should be avoided because it will result in asking countless number of questions related to reopening a question.

No.

> 4) Should I paste my question link in a stack overflow chat group and ask the members to vote for reopen?

You *can*, if you can find a specific chat room in which this would be appropriate, but this is unlikely to turn out well.  I'd personally not recommend it unless it's a particularly exceptional situation, which this doesn't appear to be.

Comment: I know my question is not exceptional but it is simple and ordinary. Right now, I know the answer and I'm sure it will be helpful to beginners who are tasked with serialization and de-serialization in c#.

Comment: @Anand Meaning do you not have a compelling need to get it reopened, as you already have an answer.  And that information is well covered in documentation for the serialize, among *many* other places already, so it's not like this is the only place someone can go to get that information (or even that it's not there, should someone happen to end up there).

Comment: sorry I didn't check the documentation. In fact, I couldn't find one when asking that question

Comment: questions are closed because they are not deemed valid. Once it is valid, then what's wrong with re-opening them

Comment: I searched for documentation but there isn't one

Comment: @Anand Make your question exceptional and I will vote to reopen it

Comment: @Anand (3 comments up) Nothing's wrong with reopening questions that deserve it, but it takes _time_. You can't expect these things to happen instantly.

Comment: @DavidZ, thanks, I will wait